# BigQuery: result set in UI and from API have different number of rows. Why?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, etl

I'm using the Python BigQuery Client Library. My connection is good, querying the same dataset, etc. Check this out:

```
queryOutput = bigquery.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=projectId,jobId=jobId,pageToken=pageToken).execute()
print('totalRows: '+str(queryOutput['totalRows']))
```

returns:

```
totalRows: 208
```

But if I take the very same query, and feed it into the BQ web UI, there are 176 rows in the result-set. Why is this happening? Why does one query have different result sets depending on which interface it's going through?

Comment: Are you sure the queries are operating over the same data?  Could the underlying tables have changed between the query job that you are calling `getQueryResults` on in python and when you're rerunning it in the web UI?  If you can share the job IDs of the two jobs that return a different number of results, we can take a look and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for replying Danny. Here's the query:

SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.page.pagePath
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([98843070.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-03-16'), TIMESTAMP('2016-03-16'))
LIMIT
  100

Doesn't seem to me that the data could be changing. How should I send you the jobId's?

Comment: Are they OK to post?

Comment: looking into @duuug 's query - i think the answer is obvious, would be good to see if it is confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting different result is in fact that (most likely) some of fields you are referencing in your SELECT are repeated (hits.hitNumber, hits.page.pagePath) and you have LIMIT 100 in place.

Now, because you do not have any ORDER BY the order is not predictable, so each time you run query you are getting different 100 rows/records which in turn have different counts of nested fields resulting in different final counts (unless you use cached results)

Hope it makes sense to you

Comment: that makes sense - I've confirmed that successive queries through the API w/ useQueryCache of the request body set to False have different counts. tricky! a good reminder to always keep in mind the behaviour of repeated fields.